# Orphaned async tasks in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

What happens if in an Azure Function an async Task is started but *orphaned* before it finishes (it is never awaited), e.g.:

```cs
[Function("FuncAsync")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> FuncAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "FuncAsync")]
    HttpRequestData req,
    FunctionContext context)
{
    var obj = FactoryClass.GetObject();     // return some object with async LongTaskAsync method
    obj.LongTaskAsync();        // async Task LongTaskAsync()

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The intention here was (I guess) to initiate a long running process and instantly return from the function.

I assume it is a bad practice but seems to work in a legacy code. I suspect there's no guarantee for the life of that async task and the azure process can be randomly winded up, when no function entry point is running/triggered.

For a console application if a running async Task is *orphaned* (and keeps running while the process terminates) it is abandoned/killed (and no exception is thrown).

```cs
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task RunFuncAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task started.");
                await Task.Delay(10 * 1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Task finished.");            // this is never executed
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);   // this is never executed
            }
        }

        static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            var t = RunFuncAsync();  // no awaiting - purposefuly
            await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting.");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Task started.
Exiting.

C:\TestTasks_Console.exe (process 6528) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

> What happens if in an Azure Function an async Task is started but
> *orphaned* before it finishes ?

The answer for the above question which you have is correct that it will get **terminated**. Azure Functions have many features that make our work a lot easier. However, stateless Azure Functions are not suitable for long running operations which would require to store a state of progress.

- For such cases the **[Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp)** are the best option. With this the restrictions on execution times no longer apply.
- The task-based programming model and **async/awai**t are well suited for mapping workflows of Durable Functions.
- If you check the [Azure Function best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices?tabs=csharp#write-robust-functions), you will also find that we should `avoid long running function` and our `function should be stateless`.
- Another option is to go for the **[WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#overview)**.  You can use Azure WebJobs to execute custom jobs as background tasks within an Azure Web App

In conclusion, we can say that stateless Azure Functions not recommended for long running operations as you may get timeout issues or like in your case may get terminated.